# array_diff to compare two associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, associative-array, array-difference

I'm confusing array_diff behavior

why genre don't exist on diff array?
Do you know how to resolve the matter?

-code

```
<?php
$array1 = array
(
    'value01' => '0',
    'value02' => 'v2',
    'genre' => '1',
    'type' => 'text',
    'contry' => 'us',
    'data' => '1',
);
$array2 = array
(
    'value01' => 'v1',
    'value02' => 'v2',
    'genre' => '0',
    'type' => 'text',
    'contry' => 'canada',
    'data' => '1',
);

print_r(array_diff($array1,$array2));
```

My result:

```
Array
(
    [contry] => us
)
```

But I expect:

```
Array
(
    [value01] => 0,
    [genre] => 1,
    [contry] => us,
);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you want to use `array_diff_assoc`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Comment: This answer is not terribly generous and doesn't not make this page a great dupe target.

Answer (score 5):

`array_diff` operates on the *values* of the array, and ignores the keys.

Because the value of `genre` in your first array is `1`, that means that if the value `1` occurs *for any key* in the second array, then the `genre` key will be removed from the first array.

Look at your arrays without the keys, and you'll see what I mean.  You essentially have two lists of values, `['0','v2','1','text','us','1']` and `['v1','v2','0','text','canada','1']`.  The only value from the first list that doesn't appear in the second is `'us'`.

I'm guessing you'll probably want to have a look at [array_key_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) or [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php).

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff_assoc` will cause Array to string conversion exception in case of multi depth associative arrays, for example arrays like these:

```
  "ip" => "127.0.0.1"
  "uri" => "follows/count"
  "body" => array:1 [
    "user_id" => 4473
  ]
```

For these types I have created a custom function which is generic, you can use that:

```
function mutidimensional_arrays_are_same(array $baseArray, array $compareArray)
{
    try {
        foreach ($baseArray as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) && isset($compareArray[$key]) && is_array($compareArray[$key])) {
                return mutidimensional_arrays_are_same($value, $compareArray[$key]);
            } else {
                if ($value != $compareArray[$key]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $err) {
        return !str_starts_with($err->getMessage(), 'Undefined ');
    }
}
```

Unlike `array_diff_assoc` it returns `boolean`