# array_diff() function not showing correct result

Tags: php, array-difference

`array_diff()` function not showing correct result:-

First Array:-

```
     Array(
    [designation_id] => 1
    [name] => Y
    [fathers_name] => Z
    [mothers_name] => F
    [spouse_name] => d
    [gender] => F
    [last_achieved_degree] => 2
    [date_of_birth] => 1960-10-17
    [date_of_joining] => 1987-02-04
)
```

Second array:-

```
 Array
    (
        [designation_id] => 9
        [name] => M
        [fathers_name] => N
        [mothers_name] => O
        [spouse_name] => 
        [gender] => M
        [last_achieved_degree] => 1
        [date_of_birth] => 1967-11-17
        [date_of_joining] => 2016-01-01
    )
```

Output:

```
    Array
(
    [name] => Y
    [fathers_name] => Z
    [mothers_name] => F
    [spouse_name] => d
    [gender] => F
    [last_achieved_degree] => 2
    [date_of_birth] => 1960-10-17
    [date_of_joining] => 1987-02-04
)
```

designation id column not showing in output result.
if designation-id value is 1 then this index not showing in output otherwise it showing. is it bug or something else?

Comment: Why not it shows?? share your raw script.

Comment: the input you shows is two different arrays?

Comment: then what should be the correct output? maybe `array_diff` isn't really what you need. and where are the codes of your trials?

Comment: user `array_diff_assoc()` instead of `array_diff()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your arrays are associative arrays, so you need to use `array_diff_assoc`:-

```
<?php

 $a =   Array(
    'designation_id' =>1,
    'name' => 'Y',
    'fathers_name' => 'Z',
    'mothers_name' => 'F',
    'spouse_name' => 'd',
    'gender' => 'F',
    'last_achieved_degree' => 2,
    'date_of_birth' => '1960-10-17',
    'date_of_joining' => '1987-02-04'
);

$b =Array
(
    'designation_id' => 9,
    'name' => 'M',
    'fathers_name' => 'N',
    'mothers_name' => 'O',
    'spouse_name' => '',
    'gender' => 'M',
    'last_achieved_degree' => 1,
    'date_of_birth' => '1967-11-17',
    'date_of_joining' => '2016-01-01',
);

echo "<pre/>";print_r(array_diff_assoc($a,$b));
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/NKbuX

To check more descriptions and examples:- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Why `array_diff()` not worked:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4742438/4248328

Answer (score 1):

`array_diff` computes the difference without comparing keys. In second array you have `[last_achieved_degree] => 1` that removes `[designation_id] => 1`.
Try `array_diff_assoc`.